# Is it possible to use glog/vlog and output to multiple log files?

Tags: c++, logging, glog

We are using Google Logger (glog/vlog C++) to output debug information.  However, we would like to output performance information to a separate log file using glog.  Is this possible?  An example of a standard call to the logger is:

```
 VLOG(1) << "This is test glog output";
```

But this seems to go to stderr/stdout.  Basically is there a way to output glog to more than one output stream/file?

Comment: did you read the documentation? https://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html

Comment: There isn't really anything there that addresses how you specify writing to different files.

Comment: Boost log has this functionality.